# Ant Design submenu collapse when clicking on menu item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I updated Ant Design from 4.12.3 to 4.13.1 due to a bug un the `Upload` component. After the update the Submenus always collapse in the Sider of my layout when I click a normal `Menu.Item` but I don't see major changes in the `Menu` component in changelogs nor bugfixes about it in newer versions. The menu code didn't change at all, did I miss something ?

Comment: I have this problem too. It's interesting that it works in codesandbox.

Comment: Yes, I didn't take time to check it yet but I'll try to handle the `openKeys` myself, it will add some code but I don't see any other solution.